# How to use Postman with Magento 1.9 SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2, postman

I can't find a good example anywhere of how to use postman application for testing the Magento 1.9 SOAP Api. The REST Api is not enough for my needs.

I have tried a POST request using https://example.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 as the URL, and in the body : raw , XML ( text/xml ) .

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <MAGE:login xmlns:MAGE="http://example.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1">
            <MAGE:username>username</MAGE:username>
            <MAGE:apiKey>password</MAGE:apiKey>
        </MAGE:login>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And the response is just the WDSL page. I'm a bit baffled by that and have tried various combinations of removing the ?wsdl=1 parameter .

Comment: Request @all magento developers : please first try to give an answer of question instead of edit..

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some odd request XML, but I suspect the main issue is posting data to a URL that includes `wsdl=1`.

Try posting to `https://example.com/api/v2_soap`

This is the XML I use, which I know works in case there is also an XML issue:

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:login soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <username xsi:type="xsd:string">{{username}}</username>
         <apiKey xsi:type="xsd:string">{{apiKey}}</apiKey>
       </urn:login>

   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`